# Get sum of a group by count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

So please imagine i have this sql table : 
User :

### id | name  | city

### 1  | name1 | city1

### 2  | name2 | city2

### 3  | name3 | city1

### 4  | name4 | city3

So until now by doing this in my controller:

```
@cities = User.group(:city).count
```

and by doing something like this in my view:

```
<%= "#{city} (#{count})" %>
```

I got this :

### city1 (2)

### city2 (1)

### city3 (1)

What i need now is to add a line which sum the count of each city like this :

### All (4)

I don't want to make a new sql query for this, because i'm pretty sure there is a cleaner way to do it.

I Hope that i was clear, thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You won't be able to do this in a single SQL query unless you craft some fancy SQL yourself. If performance is not a problem, I would aggregate this on the controller:

```
counts = User.group(:city).count
total = counts.values.sum
```

Comment: it works, well since i have no choice, i ll do it this way, thanks a lot !

Comment: If you're using this data in html it means you're never going to be handling so much data that doing this would give you performance problems. If the query was producing millions of groups then maybe you'd do 2 queries, so don't worry